# OCAML hashtbl remove specific bindings

Tags: ocaml, hashtable

I am using a hash table as a multi-mapping and I want to remove any of the previous bindings.
The Hashtbl.remove just removes the current binding.
I am thinking of something like remove hash x y which removes the binding of y to x. 
If there are more than one bindings x y it should remove one of them.
I have some working code for this but it is too complicated and slow (includes for loops  etc.)

I want it to work like this :

Hashtbl.find_all hash 1 ;;
returns [1;2;3;3;4]

remove hash 1 3 ;;

Hashtbl.find_all hash 1 ;;
returns [1;2;3;4]

Comment: Why would it not return [1;2;4]? Should hash x y only unbind one binding of x to y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this isn't really how `Hashtbl` is designed to be used, so it's not going to be particularly convenient.  There is no function in `Hashtbl` for removing or adding multiple bindings of a key, so you'll have to add and remove them one at a time. Your iterative solution is probably about as good as you can expect.

It might be better to handle multiple bindings explicitly, i.e., to bind each key to an explicit (multi-)set of values. This will give better than linear behavior when making changes to the bindings.